# Python freezes during for loop

Tags: python, loops, exit, freeze, continue

```
def get_price_history_data(ticker):
    pricelist = []
    try:
        pricedata = False
        tradingdays = 252
        Historical_Prices = pdr.get_data_yahoo(symbols=ticker, start=(datetime.today()-timedelta(tradingdays)), end=(datetime.today()))#-timedelta(years4-1)))
        price_df = pd.DataFrame(Historical_Prices)
        pricelist = price_df['Adj Close']
        pricedata = True
    except:
        print(ticker,' failed to get price data')
    return(pricelist, pricedata)

tickers = ['FB','V']

for ticker in tickers:
 [pricelist, pricedata] = get_price_data(ticker)
```

I have a list of a few thousand tickers that i run through this for loop. It outputs a single column df and a boolean. Overall it works just fine and does what I need it to. However, it inconsistently freezes indefinitely with no error message and stops running forcing me to close the program and re-run from the beginning. 
I am looking for a way for me to skip the iteration of the for loop if a certain amount of time has passed. I have looked into the time.sleep() and the continue function but cant figure out how to apply it to this specific application. If it freezes, it freezes on the "pdr.get_data_yahoo() section". Help would be apprec

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that `get_data_yahoo()` probably freezes because it's making some kind of request to a server that never gets answered.  It doesn't have a timeout option so the most obvious option is to start it in another thread/process and terminate it if it takes too long.  You can use `concurrent.futures` for that.  Once you're happy about how the code below works, you can replace `sleeps_for_a_while` with `get_price_history_data` and `(3, 1, 4, 0)` with `tickers`.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, TimeoutError
from time import sleep

TIMEOUT = 2  # seconds


def sleeps_for_a_while(sleep_for):
    print('starting {}s sleep'.format(sleep_for))
    sleep(sleep_for)
    print('finished {}s sleep'.format(sleep_for))

    # return a value to break out of the while loop
    return sleep_for * 100


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # this only works with functions that return values
    results = []
    for sleep_secs in (3, 1, 4, 0):
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
            # a future represents something that will be done
            future = executor.submit(sleeps_for_a_while, sleep_secs)
            try:
                # result() raises an error if it times out
                results.append(future.result(TIMEOUT))
            except TimeoutError as e:
                print('Function timed out')
                results.append(None)

    print('Got results:', results)
```